How to find the bounds of the expression $\|x-y\|_p$ under given constraints?
I would like to understand the bounds of the expression $\|x-y\|_p$ under the following conditions:

Constraints:

$\|x\|_1 = 1$
$\|y\|_1 = 1$
$\langle x, y \rangle = A \in [0, 1]$
$x_i, y_i \in [0, 1]$


Definitions:

$\|x\|_p = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p \right)^{1/p}$
$\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$



I am interested in finding the minimum and maximum values of $\|x - y\|_p$. Thank you for your assistance!
This is my attempt using the method of Lagrange multipliers with KKT：
For the special case when $p=2$, there is
\begin{aligned}
&L(x_i, y_i, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \lambda_i, \mu_i)\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2+\alpha\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-1\right)+\beta\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-1\right)+\gamma\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i-A\right)\\
&+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i(-x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i(-y_i)
\end{aligned}
s.t.
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\nabla L=0\\
\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{y}=1\\
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}=A\\
-\mathbf{x}\preceq 0\\
-\mathbf{y}\preceq 0\\
\lambda_i,\mu_i\ge0\\
\lambda_i(-x_i)\ge0\\
\mu_i(-y_i)\ge0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
where for $\nabla L=0$,
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}=2(x_i-y_i)+\alpha+\gamma y_i+\lambda _i=0
\end{equation}
There are too many variables here for me to solve. Is there an easier method to solve it?

Please add what you tried/your thoughts. "Solve that problem forme" without that tend to get downvoted and/or closed quickly
